# PHP - No data sent when forcing connection to close

Tags: php, browser

I have a script that is called via ajax. The script is run on an Apache 2.4.7 server and PHP 5.5.9.

The script sends back a response to the browser and after that closes the connection and continues to execute some more actions.

This is the **first method**. It doesn't work.

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "some text";
$size = ob_get_length();
ignore_user_abort(true);
header("Connection: close\r\n");
header("Content-Length: $size");
header("Content-Encoding: None", true);
ob_end_flush();     
flush(); 
ob_end_clean(); 
//after this a few actions follow
?>
```

The errors are:

- cURL: (18) transfer closed with 9 bytes remaining to read
- browser: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

This is the **second method**. It works.

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "some text";
$data = ob_get_contents();
$size = ob_get_length();
ob_end_clean(); 
ignore_user_abort(true);
header("Connection: close\r\n");
header("Content-Length: $size");
header("Content-Encoding: None", true);
echo $data;
ob_end_flush();     
flush(); 
ob_end_clean(); 
//after this a few actions follow
?>
```

This was built through trial and error and I have no idea why one works and the other doesn't.

I'm hoping you can help me figure this one out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is your last three lines:

```
ob_end_flush();     
flush(); 
ob_end_clean();
```

`ob_end_flush()` and `ob_end_clean()` both turn off the output buffering.

According to [php's ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

> To output what is stored in the internal buffer, use `ob_end_flush()`. Alternatively, `ob_end_clean()` will silently discard the buffer contents.

The combination of the two is erasing your output.

I can get your first snippet to work when I change it to:

```
ob_start();
echo "some text";
$size = ob_get_length();
ignore_user_abort(true);
header("Connection: close\r\n");
header("Content-Length: $size");
header("Content-Encoding: None", true);
ob_flush();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: @MarvinSaldinger, can you copy your script into a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) or [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and share the link?  I just tried my snippet again on another computer and it works.

Comment: I can't do that. After the ob_start() there are some included files that access the database. No other echos or anything like that. The rest is what you see.